# What was the original pronunciation of 'ä' in German?

Tags: phonetics, historical-linguistics, pronunciation, german

I always learnt it was pronounced the same as how 'e' is usually pronounced in German (in either its short or long forms respectively). But then the question is: why have a different letter for it? Surely the original sound must have been different?

Comment: It's an a that has been fronted, which is what the umlaut means in German. o vs ö, u vs. ü. Fronting often mark the plural (Mann, Männer). If the fronting of a back vowel leads it to overlap with an existing front vowel you'll get two spellings for one sound. But that's not a very strange situation. English has tons of variant spellings for many of its sounds.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Sure, but that still leaves some room for variation as to what the original sound might have been...

Answer (score 16):

“Originally” is a problematic concept. The letter “ä” was not used in Old and Middle High German. The plural of gast is gesti in OHG and geste in MHG. In early New High German the letters ä, ö and ü (or rather: a, o, u with a small superscript “e”, but I cannot find these in Unicode) were used to indicate the umlauted forms of a, o and u, but the distinction between e and ä was dictated by etymology and not by pronunciation; ä was used where there are obvious cognates with a, as in Gast  > Gäste. The spoken distinction between “e” /eː/ and “ä” /ɛː/ is essentially a spelling pronunciation adopted in the standard “Bühnenaussprache”.

Comment: The small letter *e* you're looking for is `U+0364`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a couple of questions...
Were the digraph forms (ae, oe, ue) used in OHG and MHG then?
Now, you write, "the distinction between a and ä was dictated by etymology and not by pronunciation" – does this mean there was no ablaut for the vowel "a" at all until quite recently in the history of High German?

Comment: @Noldorin I believe that's a typo: the distinction between ***e*** and ä was dictated by etymology.

Comment: @Draconis. Yes, I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @fdb Okay I think I'm happy to accept this answer, especially given it has the most up-votes... would you kindly just answer one more question first; that is, what do you mean by "spelling pronunciation"?

Comment: @Noldorin. A spelling pronunciation is when you pronounce a word the way it is spelt, not the way it has traditionally been spoken. For example, in English when you pronounce "arctic" with both "c"s sounded.

Comment: @fdb, Ah, well call that a "phonetic pronunciation". Understood though, ta.

Comment: @Noldorin The term "phonetic pronunciation" is terribly silly. It's like "hominid human" or  "gaseous air."

Answer (score 3):

Reading Siebs (19th printing, 2000—this edition introduced the notion of a relaxed *gemäßigte Hochlautung*) again, here are some facts about High German:

- In Standard German, there is no distinction between short *e* and *ä*, they are usually pronounced /ɛ/
- In Standard German, there is a distinction between long *e* and *ä*, the former is pronounced /eː/ and the latter /ɛː/
- Those two prescriptions are also in effect for *gemäßigte Hochlautung*
- Pronuncing long *ä* as /eː/ is **non-standard**

Siebs also makes a historical remark about German orthography: German orthography uses the letter *ä* when there is a related word with *a* and *e* otherwise, disregarding historical development and dialectal pronunciation. In fact, at least some German dialects make even more distinctions on the e-sounds, depending on when the *umlaut* happened (*Primärumlaut* and *Sekundärumlaut*). There are also words spelled with a long *e* that are dialectally *ä* words (e.g., *leben* "to live").

Comment: Interesting information; thank you for this. Does it tell us what the ancient pronunciation was like though?

Comment: No, Siebs only scratches the top of an iceberg here and his account is very terse.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks regardless; it’s good to know.

Answer (score 2):

If we use standard German spelling as a reference point, probably there simply never was a time when all words currently spelled with ⟨ä⟩ had one vowel sound and all words currently spelled with ⟨e⟩ had another.

The form of the modern letter ⟨ä⟩ is derived from ⟨a<sup>e</sup>⟩, which seems to have been first used in Middle High German as a means to represent a quality like [æ]. The ligature ⟨æ⟩ was also used in the same contexts.

However, it seems the same sound could also be spelled ⟨e⟩: Cercignani 2022 says "the ligature ⟨æ⟩ and the combined digraph ⟨a ͤ⟩ occurred only in Bavarian and East Alemannic manuscripts (cf. Paul/Klein 2007: 97)."). Furthermore, the places where ⟨æ⟩ and ⟨a<sup>e</sup>⟩ were used in Middle High German texts are not identical to the places where ⟨ä⟩ is used in modern German spelling, so it seems problematic (as fdb put it) to identify [æ] as the "original pronunciation of 'ä'".

#### Modern German use of ⟨e⟩ and ⟨ä⟩ is not based on words' original pronunciations

As [Sir Cornflakes says](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27925/what-was-the-original-pronunciation-of-%C3%A4-in-german/27951#27951), in Standard German **short** ⟨e⟩ and ⟨ä⟩, as in  “Ende” and “Hände”, are pronounced the same way, typically with the open-mid or 'lax' quality [ɛ]. (As in English, it is possible to transcribe this [ɛ] as /e/ in phonemic transcription, since there is no phonemic contrast in Standard German between short /e/ and short /ɛ/.) But **long** ⟨e⟩ and ⟨ä⟩ are normatively distinguished as separate phonemes, close /eː/ and open /ɛː/ respectively, although not all speakers follow this norm.

Diachronically, the Standard German short vowel [ɛ] results from the merge of as many as three prior vowel sounds. The current distribution of the two spellings ⟨e⟩ and ⟨ä⟩ does not faithfully correspond to the original pronunciation of the vowel before the merger to [ɛ]: some words now spelled with ⟨e⟩ were originally pronounced with [æ] (e.g. *Geschlecht*) and some words now spelled with ⟨ä⟩ were originally pronounced with [e] (e.g. *Gäste*). As [fdb says](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27928/5581), the use of the letter ⟨ä⟩ in standard German seems to have been affected by the orthographic principle of using the letters ⟨ä ö ü⟩ to mark umlaut as a morphological vowel change: there is a neat analogy in spelling between *Gast*-*Gäste* and other singular-plural pairs of nouns such as *Flug*-*Flüge* or *Sohn*-*Söhne*. That answers the question "why have a different letter for it?" without requiring there to be any phonetic difference between ⟨e⟩ and ⟨ä⟩.

Pace [John Frazer's answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27935/5581), the Standard German long vowel /ɛː/ was probably not invented out of nothing just for the sake of pronouncing differently-spelled words differently. Some dialects of German seem to have naturally developed and maintained a distinction in pronunciation between long /eː/ and long /ɛː/, and Cercignani 2022 argues that the contrast in Standard German between the pronunciation of long ⟨e⟩ as /eː/ and long ⟨ä⟩ as /ɛː/  was taken from dialects of this type. However, the distribution of /eː/ vs. /ɛː/ (in dialects and in the standard language) is not straightforwardly etymological, but has also been greatly affected by analogy. So even if the *existence* of the /eː/ vs. /ɛː/ distinction is not artificial in origin, we can certainly recognize that there is some "artificial" component to which words got which spelling and pronunciation in the standard.

Richter's section on "E and Ä" sums up the situation as "the present-day standard pronunciation is a consequence and not the basis of the spelling."

#### Sound changes

In Old High German, the letter ⟨e⟩ could represent either the inherited Germanic short *e vowel (as in OHG *erda* from Proto-Germanic *erþō) or the umlaut of Germanic short *a (as in OHG *gesti* from Proto-Germanic *gastīz). According to several sources I've seen, we know based on certain evidence such as rhymes that words like *erda* developed a phonetically opener quality [ɛ] whereas words like *gesti* developed a phonetically closer quality [e]: this seems counterintuitive in light of their origins, but note that in terms of environment [ɛ] occurred mainly before low vowels (since inherited *e was raised to *i in the same contexts that led to umlaut) and [e] occurred mainly before high vowels (before the loss of the conditioning factors for umlaut). (see Houlihan & Iverson 1979; also Twaddell 1938, who gives the examples *erda* and *gesti*)

At some point during or before Middle High German (this part is unclear to me) there was some "secondary umlaut" of original short **a* to a quality like [æ] (resulting in a **third** "e-like" vowel alongside [ɛ] (from original *e) and [e] (from "primary umlaut" of *a). For example, Penzl 1949 says that the clusters *ht* and *hs* inhibited the original raising of **a* to [e], so Old High German used the letter "a" rather than "e" in the spelling of words like *mahti, gislahti, wahsit,* despite the following "i". (See also Cercignani and Richter for more details.) But in Middle High German, words such as these came to develop spellings with "e", "ae" or "ä". (These spellings also show up for the umlaut of long *ā, which appears to have regularly evolved to something like [æː] or [ɛ:] in at least some dialects.)

Eventually, short [ɛ], [e], [æ] all merged together, but a number of German dialects, per Cercignani, retained more than one corresponding long vowel (which developed from sources like lengthening of the short vowels as well as from original long vowels); Cercignani argues that dialects of this type are the basis of the prescribed standard German vowel system with /ɛ/, /ɛː/, /eː/. However, the distribution of vowel sounds in the standard is clearly not just a straightforward continuation of 'original' vowel sounds: it is certain that analogy has played a large role in the distribution of /ɛː/ and /eː/ in any modern German variety, regardless of whether the  contrast occurs naturally or artificially. Cercignani gives long descriptions of how analogy has affected various forms, e.g. plurals.

Some relevant quotes from Cercignani 2022:

- > the coalescence of /æ/, /ɛ/, and /e/ took place at different times and/or in different types of speech in late Old or early Middle High German. Further, that the reduced incidence of /ɛ/ and /e/ caused by lengthening (chiefly in an open syllable and before /r/ plus consonant) favoured the subsequent merger of /e/ and /ɛ/. The resulting /ɛ/ was then accepted by the New High German “Schriftsprache” and eventually preserved by Present Standard German. Examples with older /æ/, /ɛ/, and /e/ are Geschlecht (OHG gislahti, MHG geslehte, geslähte), Recht (OHG recht, MHG recht), and fest (OHG festi, MHG feste).
- > The orthography of the Middle and early New High German period is ambiguous and therefore unreliable as evidence of a merger of /ɛ:/ to identity with /e:/. The traditional spelling for /ɛ:/ was ⟨e⟩, while the ligature ⟨æ⟩ and the combined digraph ⟨a ͤ ⟩ occurred only in Bavarian and East Alemannic manuscripts (cf. Paul/Klein 2007: 97).
- > the acceptance of the distinction between the two phonemes in general
  > usage was certainly encouraged by morphological/etymological considerations which led to the use of ⟨ä⟩ (and consequently of /ɛ:/) in words with original /e:/ (as in zählen, MHG zelen) and forms with earlier /a:/ (as in Hähne, MHG hanen). But the fact that these modifications were due to prescriptive tendencies promoted by grammarians, printers, and linguistic societies does not imply that the distinction between /ɛ:/ and /e:/ was invented, since it occurred in regional types of speech that made their way into the New High German “Schriftsprache”.
- > the fact that Central and Upper German areas may have, for example, /ɛ:/ in leben but /e:/ in heben and legen can only confirm the phonological origin of /ɛ:/ as opposed to /e:/. In these types of speech OHG /ɛ/ with subsequent lengthening (OHG lebēn, weban) merged with /ɛ:/ – whereas in others it merged with /e:/ (cf. above) – and this phoneme was kept apart from /e:/ derived from OHG /e/ with subsequent lengthening (MHG heben, OHG heffen; OHG legen < *lagjan). Regional usage cannot be expected to agree with standard usage, which is often the result of a complex process of linguistic levelling.

### References

- Cercignani, Fausto. 2022. "[The development of the Old High German umlauted vowels and the reflex of New High German /ɛ:/ in Present Standard German](https://www.redalyc.org/journal/6645/664572589005/html/)". *Linguistik online,* vol. 113, núm. 1, pp. 45-57.
- Houlihan, Kathleen & Iverson, Gregory K., 1979, "[Functionally-constrained Phonology](https://publish.iupress.indiana.edu/read/current-approaches-to-phonogical-theory/section/713c57ef-acaf-4962-98e1-58af0c342e75#ch3fn_9)", in *Current Approaches to Phonological Theory,* ed. Daniel Dinnsen,
- Penzl, Herbert. "Umlaut and Secondary Umlaut in Old High German." *Language,* Vol. 25, No. 3 (Jul. - Sep., 1949), pp. 223-240.
- Richter, Helmut. "[German vowels over time](https://hhr-m.de/de-vowels/history/#tab_vowels)". Published 2004-01-03, modified 2015-07-25.
- Twaddell, W. Freeman. 1938. “A note on Old High German umlaut.” Monatshefte für deutschen Unterricht 30:177-81.

### Further reading

- "[The influence of Standard German on the vowels and diphthongs of West Central Bavarian](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122225957id_/https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F10485A5AE7A19AB17A7DBDFFE6763A0/S0025100321000232a.pdf/div-class-title-the-influence-of-standard-german-on-the-vowels-and-diphthongs-of-west-central-bavarian-div.pdf)", Katrin Wolfswinkler & Jonathan Harrington, 2021
- "[wie spät ist es?](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/11/wie-spat-ist-es.html)", John Wells’s phonetic blog, 24 November 2011
- "[German [a(ː)]](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/09/german.html)", John Wells’s phonetic blog, 23 September 2009

Answer (score 1):

Until rather recently, *ä* represented the sound /ɛ/, also called "epsilon". This is similar to the sound of *e* (conveniently written /e/), but with the tongue slightly lower: it's the vowel in English "pet". Some German-speakers still use this pronunciation, but only when they're speaking carefully—that is, it takes conscious effort to get it "right". In casual everyday speech, it's merged into /e/ over the last century.

It's not clear what the "original" sound was, but we can make a guess. The process of front-umlaut in German (and other Germanic languages) involved shifting vowels forward in the mouth in certain contexts. *ö* /ø/ is *o* /o/ shifted forward, for instance, and the same for *ü* /y/ from *u* /u/.

So based on this evidence, we could say that the "original" underlying phoneme for *ä* might have been /æ/, a low front vowel (the sound in General American "cat"). But this is nothing but an educated guess. The difference between the actual sounds [æ] and [ɛ] is rather small, and I don't know of any evidence that would tell us conclusively that it was originally pronounced [æ].

Comment: You’ve left out length markers, which is confusing in this case. In modern standard German, “ä” does represent  /ɛ/ (as in “Hände”), and so does the letter “e” (as in “Ende”). They only represent /e:/ when the vowel is long (or, allophonically, short [e] may occur in unstressed syllables in words from languages like Latin).

Comment: @sumelic I thought long and short *e* were considered to be /e e:/, with the quality difference being purely phonetic? Unfortunately my study of German was a long time ago and I might be misremembering.

Comment: @sumelic All the material I have on German says that /ɛ/ is now /e/ except in artificial speech, and that’s what I hear from the natives, too (I live in Nordrhein-Westphalia). Draconis: Re: /æ/, isn’t /æ/ in General American [eə]~[ɛə]? I think Scandinavian /æ/ is a better candidate to what German ‹ä› probably represented.

Comment: @boiko I'm used to General American not breaking any of its vowels, but that's entirely possible. Is there a Scandinavian language that has a nice clean [æ]? (I'm afraid I don't speak any of them.)

Comment: While for short vowels, there is no difference between *e* and *ä*, there are still speakers of German distinguishing long *e* and *ä*, a minimal pair is formed by *Beeren* and *Bären*. All German speakers make the distinction in the name of the letters, they are just /e:/ for *e* and /ɛ:/ for *ä*. It is also a regional thing, in the northwest of Germany the distinction between long *e* and *ä* is not made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, just to be clear, you're surmising the original pronunciation of Bär probably shared the first sound in common with modern English RP "bat" or "bad"?

Comment: @Noldorin Yes, though it's nothing more than a guess: we don't have evidence of how it was actually pronounced until quite recently.

Comment: Yep, fair enough. A lot of historical phonetics is reconstructive, so that doesn't surprise me much.

Comment: @Noldorin fdb's answer also gives evidence that it was originally /e/, just the same as "e", and the difference I mention only arose later because of the spelling. But it's hard to be sure: there might have been a pronunciation difference from the start, but not a letter for it (so the writing system concealed the difference), or both possibilities might have been true in different dialects.

Comment: @Draconis: re: /æ/: er, I thought so, but upon a closer look, apparently not. I was taught a nice clear distinct /æ/ in Norwegian class, but the real examples I can find on Forvo seem to lean to either [a] or [ɛ] most of the time. And the other North Germanic languages seem to have already merged or broken it (modern Icelandic is [aj]).  I guess pure [æ] is a hard vowel? Sill, conservative Norwegian should at least have it [sometimes](https://forvo.com/word/l%C3%A6r/#no).  Maybe [Finnish](https://forvo.com/word/%C3%A4%C3%A4ri/#fi) is a safer bet (tho no /ɛ/ phoneme in it for a minimum pair).

Comment: The sound in General American *kitty* corresponds to *Kätzchen*, that is not *Katze* “cat”. You do of course have *kid* all over the place, thus Ger. *Kitz*. But you also have *cunt* for *pussy*, so ...

Comment: @vectory While I'm not a native speaker, I don't think I've ever heard ä pronounced /ɪ/.

Answer (score 1):

As far as modern Standard German (Hochdeutsch) is concerned, (1) **'ä' is merely an orthographic device** whose sound value is the same as 'e' in the same position; (2) there *is* some **vacillation** among speakers when it comes to the long vowel; the short variant is always [ɛ] unless someone wants to sound comical.

Standard pronunciation suggests to read long 'ä' as [ɛ:] as contrasted with long 'e' [e:], but this is **not generally followed** except for a few isolated cases like the interjection 'äh' [ʔɛ:] (people often perform sounds in interjections that they'd otherwise claim not to say at all, like the click in E. 'tsk').

The reason standard pronunciation wants us to read 'ä' as [ɛ:] at all comes from the misunderstanding that where there's a separate way to write words, there should also be a separate way to read those words. Needless to say, this idea fails in many places, not least of which is the contrast of short 'ä' and 'e', which are undisputedly always [ɛ]. There's also some utility to keeping [e:] ~ [ɛ:] separate as there are a few minimal pairs that would otherwise sound the same, such as Beeren ~ Bären (berries, bears) and Ehre ~ Ähre (honor, ear of corn).

So why do people not follow and keep [e:] ~ [ɛ:] separate? One, because it is **artificially introduced**, phonetically **not very salient** and, usage-wise, **not very useful distinction** to be made, as only a handful of lexical items profit from the distinction. Also, there's a **constant interference from the many dialects** that have only the one or the other vowel, or, when they have both, use them in ways that conflict with what the standard would have us do. As in other languages, most people do not natively speak the perfect standard natively; rather, it is an acquired dialect that is approximated from the sound-base of what one grew up talking.

One reason why **one should definitely not follow the folly and separate [e:] ~ [ɛ:]** is because it's at odds with the overall German vowel system. German has 7 simple full vowels, viz. /a,e,i,o,u,ø,y/ (plus schwa), all of which come in a short and a long variant. The short ones are generally laxer / more open than the tenser / more closed long ones, so [a, ɛ, ɪ, ɔ, ʊ, œ, ʏ] contrast with [a:, e:, i:, o:, u:, ø:, y:]. An extra [ɛ:] does not fit well into this symmetry.

(There's yet another variant for each vowel that is used mainly in words of Latin or Greek origin; these are described as being a mixture of the short and the long ones in that the vowel quality is rather tense, but the quantity is short or half-long, which gives [aˑ, eˑ, iˑ, oˑ, uˑ, øˑ, yˑ]).

As for why an extra letter Ää was introduced into the spelling when it doesn't correspond to a sound of its own, well, that's a good question. On the one hand, using 'ä' to mark the Umlaut does tie related words together, so you can immediately see that 'Korn', 'Körner', 'Fluss', 'Flüsse' and 'Lachen', 'Lächeln' are related. OTOH we write a lot of words with 'ö' and 'ü' that do **not** have a modern counterpart with 'ä', 'o', 'u', ex. 'Öl' (*Ol), 'Süden' (*Suden), 'Ähre' (*Ahre). Worse, **there are lots of historical Umlaut vowels that are not marked in the orthography at all**, ex. 'Gewitter' (<Wetter), 'Gebirge' (<Berg), and then there's a fair number of high-frequency words where usage has been **non-uniform** over the past one or two hundred years, ex. 'ächt'-'echt', 'Ältern'-'Eltern', 'Stängel'-'Stengel', 'enbläuen'-'einbleuen'.

Comment: It is quite funny to argue that the contrast e : ä be artificially introduced in a *completely artificial* system like *Deutsche Bühnenaussprache*. You want to set your own prescriptionism against the prescriptionism of Siebs.

Comment: I do not want to introduce a new vowel contrast, I'm saying that it has been done. I'm arguing against prescribing [e:] ~ [ɛ:] because I think it doesn't fit the vowel system well, and, descriptively speaking, many speakers do not follow that rule. What the OP learned—don't make a distinction in speech between 'e' and 'ä'—is what I support, and I'm saying the distinction is in fact originally purely orthographic, and the phonetic distinction was later grafted on.

Answer (score -4):

*Umlaut* has been an obscure problem in Germanistic. It is usually identified with the influence of a high vowel, similar to Gothic *ai* and Norse breaking, but effective across consonants. So *Apfel ~ Äpfel* may be compared to **applu ~ *appliwi, applō*, cf. EWAhd:

> Singularformen, welche schon ahd. mit Umlaut-e erscheinen (wie vielfach
> mundartlich heute, s. u.), sind wohl der Analogie des
> vorwiegend gebrauchten Pl. zu verdanken (schwerlich analog den relativ seltenen Diminutivformen, →
> *epfilî*).

> [https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/apful/de#apful]

See also for example *Elch* "elk", **algiz*.

[Primär Umlaut] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?=bq0bF4k1i_A&t=3620s) applies only to the vowel *a*.

Based on the idiom “für'n Appel und'n Ei”, if a staff rhyme, it may be presumed that umlaut was diphtongized under influence of Low German (High German Consonant shift demands *[affaltar](https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/affoltra/de#affaltar) < *apul-drō* “Apple-tree”) in origin closer to *Ei* < **ajjiz* “Egg", see also *eh-, je*, *Ehe* and *ewig* < *[êwa](https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/%C3%AAwa1/de#%C3%AAwa1) * < **aiw-i/a-*.

See by the way *Kaizerreich* [ˈkʰaɪzɐˌʁaɪç], OHG *keisur*, Old Saxon *kēsur*, Old Frankish *kēser, keiser* < L. *Caesar*, compare modern High German *Caesar*, *Cesar*, *Cäser* as proper names:

> [ˈt͡s***ɛː***zaʁ] (standard; used naturally in western Germany and Switzerland)

> [ˈt͡s***eː***zaʁ] (overall more common; particularly northern and eastern regions)

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Caesar#German]

Talk about *the big cheese*, *the hot shit*, cp. *das ist doch Käse*, read **scheiße* "shit"?

The merger with *e* is not complete and the distinction is sounding to my native ears quite forced (cf. “Bühnenaussprache”, @fdb, above). Notable examples begin with *w*:

1. conj. *wegen*, vb. *erwägen*, cp. En. *way* and *weigh*. The same applies though less frequently to
2. conj. *während* and part. *(sich) erwehrend*, cp. *Wesen, gewesen*, respectively *Wehrmacht*.

Talk about *the big cheese* (certainly not **kāsī* > *cheese, Käse*).

The fact of the matter is that the conjunction is stressed differently and the phonetic-phonology interface is confused. Conj. *weil* "while" may turn out a short vowel, for example. *Waagen* on the other hand shows monophthong in relation with *wägen*, although *Wagen* "wagon" is usually considered a cognate homophone (pl. *Wägen*, cp. pl.dat *Wege-n*). The concept of so-called underlying phonology completely breaks down at this point and the question stops making sense because different idiolects employ different phonologies. It is prosody, not phonology which is making the difference and probably always has. The lengthened vowel of *Waage* may be explained by lenghened plurals productive into Middle High German. Vb. *wägen* must be formed by analogy from *wegen*, as the consistent pronounciation of *erwägen* shows (cp. OHG *wegan*, but En. *wager*).

---

In conclusion, answers above refer the spelling to etymology, "affected by etymological and morphological considerations" @asteroids, "dictated by etymology", @fdb, except this is etymology of the previous centuries. This suffers from the reductive analytical view, in which a word exists in isolation outside phraseology.

To return to the initial example, distinction in the singular *Apfel* is justified by neighbouring r, *der Apfel* "the apple tree", potentially from an unshifted form of PIE *dórw- "tree, wood" in a Saxon genitive, Verner variant OHG *ter, affal-ter*, expected Grimm variant *Zier-Apfel* in fact attested. The original determiners are quite difficult to determine, hence more research is needed.